# How to install odoo in ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, odoo

> When I trying to Install dependency python-passlib using command " sudo apt-get install python-passlib" getting error like this.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-passlib is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-passlib' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe use apt-cache search passlib to see if the package is named slightly differently.

if you don't find an ubuntu package, you can maybe install passlib using pip.

if you still run into dependency issues, maybe go for an own virtualenv (use python-virtualenv), so you can install whatever you need.